# Why i am not able to log into user Santosh?

Tags: linux

I tried to channge the user from root to Santosh but i am not able to do so.

[root@ localhost ~] # su -santosh

-bash-3.1 $

Comment: That's a different shell - are you sure you haven't changed user? What's `whoami` say? And you know you should have a space between the `-` and the `santosh` in the `su` line I think?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [su(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html) man page, you can see that you are running

```
su -s antosh
```

which tries to switch to root using the shell antosh. This is probably not what you want. To change the user to santosh do:

```
su santosh
```

or if you want to run a login shell

```
su -l santosh
```

or

```
su - santosh
```

The space after `-` is very important.